# Copy paste Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make J3:N3 = T2:X2, then I want to copy the cells formulas of T2:X2 and paste, jump one and paste and so on. The code runs fine, but does not apply my formulas in any of the cells. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
WsScenarios.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[-10]"
Range("T2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:X2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Set RgnCopy = Range("T2:X2")

i = 4
Do While i <= LastRow    
  RgnCopy.Copy
  Range(Cells(i, 20), Cells(i, 24)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
  i = i + 2        
Loop
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not apply my formulas in any of the cells"? do the cells remain blank?

Comment: (a) What is the address of `ActiveCell` when your code starts?  (b) What formula is in `T2` when your code starts (assuming `T2` is not the `ActiveCell`)? (c) What is the value of `LastRow`?

Comment: A.S.H yes remains blank. i just want the make J3:N3 = T2:X2. s0 if j3 is 5 make T2 5..

Comment: So i select t2 and then make =J3. that is the formula. LastRow is 147.

Comment: To avoid any chance of having selected the wrong cell (and thus applying the formula in the wrong location) change `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[-10]"` `Range("T2").Select` to `Range("T2").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[-10]"`.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K. it is working fine now. =)

Answer (score 0):

Recording a macro using the Excel UI could be useful sometimes, but what matters more is to write the code in a way to get done what you want in a better way. Also you have to think about maintaning or developing the code more in future so I suggest to remove every element that is an indication of using the UI such as activating sheets, or getting inputs  from the user through activecell, Select method etc.

As mentioned in one of the previous comments using Range("T2").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[-10]" would solve your problem, but if you consider two ranges as the origin and destination, then you can always do the job a lot faster and better with the least hassle to parametrise the code in a later time:

```
Sub CopyIt()
    Dim rngOrigin As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    Set rngOrigin = WS.Range("T2:X2")
    Set rngDestination = WS.Range("J3:N3")

    rngDestination.NumberFormat = "General"
    rngOrigin.Copy
    rngDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

Comment: why score down?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's because you haven't provided any explanation of what was causing the OPs problem, and how your code resolves it. "Code-splat" answers generally aren't well received.

Comment: Just add the explanation and it should go up again, stack overflow is meant to point out where we are wrong in our questions and not just "here you are". It helps us to learn why and how in order to be more analytical under that scope next time.

Comment: I added an explanation to explain how I meant to help, hope this work!